# Certificat SSL for Apache signed BY Microsoft PKI

Tags: ssl

i have already installed OCS-Inventory, it works in my server with the CACERT.PEM i have generated in the ocs server and i self signed it . but when i try to deploy it in my network , it dosent ,the active directory dosent allow that . i think the ad is acting like a CA in my network i have to sign my certificat with active directory then deploy again in my ocs server , could you help me pls. 
log file is :
Starting OCS Inventory NG Agent on Tuesday, January 16, 2018 17:24:08.
AGENT => Running OCS Inventory NG Agent Version 2.1.1.1
AGENT => Using OCS Inventory NG FrameWork Version 2.1.1.1
AGENT => Loading plug-in(s)
AGENT => Using network connection with Communication Server
AGENT => Using Communication Provider  Version <2.1.1.1>
AGENT => Sending Prolog
ERROR *** AGENT => Failed to send Prolog 
AGENT => Unloading communication provider
AGENT => Unloading plug-in(s)
AGENT => Execution duration: 00:00:01.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in my ssl certificat. well now i m using lets encrypte certificat it works well . but before install the agent. rename the name of your certificat to cacert.pem , because the agent configuration file in the : C:\ProgramData\OCS Inventory NG\Agent ocsinventoryagent.ini  contain cacert.pem in its config so if u use another name it will not works .